# Huge Heap Mem Usage for a Simple Task

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to understand what is going on in a basic flink stream job.

I have a basic flink job which reads from kafka as string, in a flatmap makes some string operations and sends messages back to kafka as string. No window or state.
1 kafka source and 8 kafka sinks.
Message count is about 25K/second.
When I check the task manager on Flink UI, I see that heap memory usage sometimes goes up to 10G. When I watch it I see that it changes something between 3GB-10GB.

I configured heap memory to 500MB and it seems it is working without any problem. heap usage is around 200-400MB
If I configure heap memory to 10GB , then heap usage metric of task manager on Flink UI is differs between 3-10GB.

I took a heap dump of task manager and analyzed it Visual Vm. It shows heap usage only  23MB. Why?
I enabled GC logs and where you can see a sample :

`Memory usage stats: [HEAP: 3851/9208/9208 MB, NON HEAP: 84/89/744 MB (used/committed/max)]`

So where is this 5GB-6GB . For just a basic stream job, why flink is using this much memory?

The real problem is, when I deploy the other jobs, after a while, taskmanager crushes without any trace so I assume I have an OOM error.

Comment: Why do you have 8 Kafka sinks? And how are you splitting your input stream into the 8 streams for these sinks?

Comment: According the incoming data type, I feed 8 different Kafka topics. The idea is, read from a topic. Check the message type and forward the message to related topic.

Comment: If you're using a flatMap then how are you sinking to different topics based on the message type? In any case, Flink will be creating a lot of temp objects, so normally you'd see heap usage increase, and then regularly drop as GCs happen.

Comment: I use filter(). Yes the answer is temp objects in the heap. Periodicly they drop by GC. Thanks